# How to load inner spreadsheet inside an excel spreadsheet into pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a spreadsheet with spreadsheets inside of it.

[image: Img of excel sheet]

The spreadsheet I'm using is here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10NXgp5L1y2W6HA6f875Vh7uFFuPi9iM1

This is my code

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('t1-7.xlsx')

print(df)

print("\n\n\n\n")

print(df.iloc[:,2][8])
```

Instead of the inner spreadsheet that I expected, it returns the name in the cell that is supposed to show me the spreadsheet.

Output

```
           Contents  ...                                         Unnamed: 3
0               NaN  ...                                                NaN
1  Type of Dwelling  ...                                                NaN
2               NaN  ...                                                NaN
3               NaN  ...  Resident Households by Type of Dwelling, House...
4               NaN  ...  Resident Households by Type of Dwelling, Ethni...
5               NaN  ...  Resident Households by Type of Dwelling, Marit...
6               NaN  ...  Resident Households by Type of Dwelling, Ethni...
7               NaN  ...  Resident Households by Type of Dwelling and Ag...
8               NaN  ...  Resident Households by Type of Dwelling and Hi...
9               NaN  ...  Resident Households by Type of Dwelling and Oc...
[10 rows x 4 columns]




6.0
```

Comment: Why are you expecting `read_excel` to follow links to another sheet? How is it supposed to merge all these different sheets in case they don't have the same structure? That's such a specific and unusual use case. You should use the `sheet_name` argument of `read_excel` to access each sheet directly.

Comment: I got an argument does not exist error when i used `sheet_name` as an arg

Comment: I think I used `sheet_names` as an arg lol.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `sheet_name` arg when reading the excel file

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('t1-7.xlsx', sheet_name="T1")
```

You can pass a list into the sheet_name argument to read more than one inner spreadsheet.